# How to find header Control In Repeater?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am finding Header control in Repeater in C#

```
HtmlGenericControl nameposition = null;
                          nameposition = (HtmlGenericControl)Repeater1.Controls[0].Controls[0].FindControl("tweet-container");
```

I am getting Error How to use it?.Aspx Code

```
<div  id="tweet-container" runat="server"> </div>
```

Comment: Where is the repeater markup? Where is the "header" markup? Where exactly in your code behind are you trying to access the repeater?

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

So if its a server control you can simply use:
 **In Repeater_ItemDataBound event**

```
   HtmlGenericControl divControl = e.Item.FindControl("tweet-container") as HtmlGenericControl;
```